# Abstract Azure IMobileServiceTable<T> behind repository

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, iqueryable, ddd-repositories

I want my repsository to be independent of the data access technology. Currently I am working on a Xamrin.Forms App that uses Azure Mobile App Services for data access. For performance and flexibility reasons I want my repository to look simmilar like the following:

```
Task<IEnumerable<IDomainObject>> GetDomainObjectAsync(Func<IQueryable<IDomainObject>, IQueryable<IDomainObject>> query)
```

Suppose my `IDomainObject` looks like the following:

```
public interface IDomainObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and my DataAccess Object:

```
internal class AzureDomainObject : IDomainObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I found out and tested I can do the following to query the database within my repository implementation:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IDomainObject>> GetDomainObjectAsync(Func<IQueryable<IDomainObject>, IQueryable<IDomainObject>> query)
{
    // _table of type IMobileServiceTable<AzureDomainObject> gotten by MobileServiceClient
    var tableQuery = _table.GetQuery();
    tableQuery.Query = tableQuery.Query.Take(4); // 1) this was for testing and it works (ordering etc also works)
    // tableQuery.Query = query(tableQuery.Query); // 2) this was my initial idea how to use the input param
    await _table.ReadAsync(tableQuery);
}
```

My poblem now is how to use the input param `query` to replace 1) with 2).

`tableQuery.Query` expects an `IQueryable<AzureDomainObject>` but `query` is of type `IQueryable<IDomainObject>`.

Neither `.Cast<AzureDomainObject>()` nor `.OfType<AzureDomainObject>()` work to convert. Nor does `(IQueryable<IAzureDomainObject>)query;` work.

Cast and OfType throw `NotSupportedException` and the hard cast throws an `InvalidCastException`.

I also tried to extract the `Expression` from the `query` input param and assign it to the `tableQuery.Query`. But then a runtime exception occurs that they are not compatible.

Another idea I had was to use the `ReadAsync(string)` overload and pass the string representation of the passed `query` param. But this way I don't know how to generate the string.

So the final question is: Does anyone knows how to hide both `AzureDomainObject` and `IMobileServiceTable` from the domain model but keep the flexibility and performance benefits of `IQueryable` in the repository interface?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I checked this issue and here is my implementation for this scenario, you could refer to them.

**Model:**

```
public class TodoItem : IDomainObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}

public interface IDomainObject
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface IAzureCloudTableRepository<T> where T : IDomainObject
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDomainObjectAsync(Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> query);
}


public class AzureCloudTableRepository<T> : IAzureCloudTableRepository<T> where T : IDomainObject
{
    IMobileServiceTable<T> table;

    public AzureCloudTableRepository(MobileServiceClient client)
    {
        this.table = client.GetTable<T>();
    }

    public async Task<T> CreateItemAsync(T item)
    {
        await table.InsertAsync(item);
        return item;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDomainObjectAsync(Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> query)
    {
        var tableQuery = this.table.CreateQuery();
        tableQuery.Query = tableQuery.Query.Take(4); //the internal fixed query
        tableQuery.Query = query(tableQuery.Query);  //the external query
        return await tableQuery.ToEnumerableAsync();
    }
}
```

**TEST:**

```
var mobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net");
var todoitem = new AzureCloudTableRepository<TodoItem>(mobileService);
var items = await todoitem.GetDomainObjectAsync((query) =>
{
    return query.Where(q => q.Text!=null);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Indeed this works, but only because you expose TodoItem to the Client  which makes the abstraction IDomainObject obsolete. TodoItem is part of the data access layer because it exposes the ID and even either must have the same name as the azure datatable or must get an attribute with the table name. Either it exposes Data access layer specifics to the domain, which I tried to avoid. After some further  reading I decided to leave IQueryable alone and use other mechanism. Nevertheless, great to read your thoughts!